# Trying to merge two linked lists into one, doubly LL. first term being skipped

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

```
/*this program is ment to put the terms of 2 different linked lists
into a single one*/
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct dnode
{
     struct dnode* prev;
     int info;
     struct dnode* next;
};

struct dnode *h1 = NULL;
struct dnode *h2 = NULL;
struct dnode *t2 = NULL;
struct dnode *t1 = NULL;

//now the new guy
struct dnode *head = NULL;
struct dnode *tail = NULL;

void ins1(int x)
{
    struct dnode*current = (struct dnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));
    struct dnode*temp = (struct dnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));
    current = t1;
    temp->info = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (t1 == NULL) {
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = NULL;
        h1 = temp;
        t1 = temp;
        current = temp;
    } else {
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = current;
        current->next = temp;
        current = temp;
        t1 = current;
    }
}

void ins2(int x)
{
    struct dnode *current = (struct dnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));
    struct dnode *temp = (struct dnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));
    current = t2;
    temp->info = x;
    temp->next = NULL;
    if (t2 == NULL) {
        temp->prev = NULL;
        temp->next = NULL;
        h2 = temp;
        h1 = temp;
        current = temp;
    } else {
        temp->next = NULL;
        temp->prev = current;
        current->next = temp;
        current = temp;
        t2 = current;
    }
}

void shuffleswitch()
{
    struct dnode *current = (struct dnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));
    struct dnode *temp = (struct dnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));
    struct dnode *c1 = (struct dnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));
    struct dnode *c2 = (struct dnode *) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));
    current = head;
    c1 = h1;
    c2 = h2;
    int iter = 1;
    if (h1 == NULL && h2 == NULL)
        printf("it is an empty set of lists\n");
    else {
        while ((c1 != NULL) || (c2 != NULL)) {
            if (iter % 2 != 0) {
                if (c1 == NULL) {
                    iter++;
                    continue;
                } else if (head == NULL) {
                    temp->info = c1->info;
                    temp->next = NULL;
                    temp->prev = NULL;
                    current = temp;
                    head = current;
                    tail = current;
                    iter++;
                    c1 = c1->next;
                } else {
                    temp->info = c1->info;
                    temp->next = NULL;
                    temp->prev = current;
                    current = temp;
                    tail = current;
                    iter++;
                    c1 = c1->next;
                }
            } else {
                if(c2 == NULL) {
                    iter++;
                    continue;
                } else if(head==NULL) {
                    temp->info = c2->info;
                    temp->next = NULL;
                    temp->prev = NULL;
                    current = temp;
                    head = current;
                    tail = current;
                    iter++;
                    c2 = c2->next;
                } else {
                    temp->info = c2->info;
                    temp->next = NULL;
                    temp->prev = current;
                    current = temp;
                    tail = current;
                    iter++;
                    c2 = c2->next;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

void disp()
{
    struct dnode *current = (struct dnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));
    current = head;
    if (head == NULL) {
        printf("there are no terms in the new LL\n");
    } else {
        while (current != NULL) {
            int t = current->info;
            printf("value %d\n",t);
            if (current->next == NULL)
                break;
            else
                current = current->next;
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    printf("Hi,I am in main\n");
    ins1(5);
    ins2(6);
    shuffleswitch();
    disp();
}
```

So what's happening here is `ins1()` inputs a `5` into the code, but that's not being seen in the output.
As `isn1()` and `ins2()` are symmetric, there shouldn't be an error.

**My logic for the shuffle switch was as follows:**

First check whether there are terms to add (while loop).
Now check, which needs to be added.
If the list is empty, continue as the other one might be. Add to this new linked list at the end/last depending on the needs.

Comment: Just assign the address of head of second link list to the tail of first link list. your program looks way more complicated than your question

Comment: how do you want to merge them because i don't get it?... `struct dnode*current=(struct dnode*)malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));

current=head;` from your code will generate a memory leak there is no need for malloc there.

Comment: Check my example here: https://pastebin.com/mScMkkdy (there is a qsort implementation for the double linked lists which splits and joins the lists inside).

Comment: `struct dnode*temp = (struct dnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode *));`  `temp` is not given enough space. --> `struct dnode*temp = (struct dnode*) malloc(sizeof(struct dnode));`